# How can I include authorization Headers in my react-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, http-headers, authorization

On postman, I can access endpoints by adding the headers:

Key: Value ( I will insert fake figures for example)

`x-mash-auth-token: gdjsjaosh-hkds-dhjsk-hjjdbahsj`

I am building a react app that allows user to search endpoints, how can I include this header in my code to grant user access on UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            axios({
                url: "API URL",
                method: "GET",
                data: {name: "abc"},
                contentType: 'application/json',
                headers: {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer gdjsjaosh-hkds-dhjsk-hjjdbahsj',
                    'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': "jwt_token"
                },
                responseType: 'json'
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                successCallback(response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                errorCallback(error);
            })
```